# Can a Symfony Form map fields from form to entity?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Is it possible to do this?:

```
// Entity/User.php

<?php

namespace Entity

class User {

 private $name;
 private $id;

 public function __construct($name) {
   $this->name = $name;
 }

 // getters and setters

}

// IndexController

<?php
    ...
   if($form->isValid())
       $user = $form->mapData(User::class);
```

So I dont have to instantiate a new user like this:

```
<?php
    ...
    if ($form->idValid) {
       $userData = new User($form->get('name')->getData());
       $this->updateUser($form->get('id')->getData(), $userData);
    }
```

The root of what I'm trying to achieve is to pass data to a Command and CommandHandler to edit the user info in the User Edit page.
I thought about passing an ID to a function, an data, but I want to make sure that the data passed to the Command Handler (data which should be in Command) is the one I need, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: What's your existing form class look like?  Is your only question how to map a form to an entity?  Or do you have that working and are trying to figure out something else?

Comment: Why not avoid `__constructor()` arguments or make it optional? I meant, you've `setName()` method, no?